# Tensorflow-Lite : Exporting a GraphDef from tf.Session convert failed

Tags: android, python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I want to convert my tensorflow Spectrogram session to `.tflite` file for using in Android.
I try to follow the TFLite [official example](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/python_api#exporting_a_graphdef_from_tfsession_) but it is failed during the convert procedure.
Please give me some advice for fixing this error. Thanks a lots!

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.signal import stft

# Waveform placeholder
waveform = tf.placeholder(name="waveform", dtype=tf.float32, shape=(4000))

# Compute the spectrogram and get the asolute values
stfts = stft(waveform, frame_length=256, frame_step=64, fft_length=256)
spectrograms = tf.abs(stfts)   

def TF_spectrogram(audio):
    # Run the spectrogram session
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        # Run the computation graph and save the png encoded image to a file
        spectrogram = sess.run(spectrograms, feed_dict={waveform: audio}) 
        print("The Spectrogram size (shape) is : " + str(spectrogram.shape) + ", type : " + str(type(spectrogram)))  
        return spectrogram

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_session(sess, [waveform], [spectrograms])
    tflite_model = converter.convert()
    open("spectrogram.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

I got the error message from Jupyter Notebook

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ConverterError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-a94c03f6a5ae> in <module>
      2     sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
      3     converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_session(sess, [waveform], [spectrograms])
----> 4     tflite_model = converter.convert()
      5     open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)

F:\Anaconda3\envs\tf_py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\lite.py in convert(self)
    896           input_tensors=self._input_tensors,
    897           output_tensors=self._output_tensors,
--> 898           **converter_kwargs)
    899     else:
    900       result = _toco_convert_graph_def(

F:\Anaconda3\envs\tf_py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\convert.py in toco_convert_impl(input_data, input_tensors, output_tensors, *args, **kwargs)
    402   data = toco_convert_protos(model_flags.SerializeToString(),
    403                              toco_flags.SerializeToString(),
--> 404                              input_data.SerializeToString())
    405   return data
    406 

F:\Anaconda3\envs\tf_py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\convert.py in toco_convert_protos(model_flags_str, toco_flags_str, input_data_str)
    170       stderr = _try_convert_to_unicode(stderr)
    171       raise ConverterError(
--> 172           "TOCO failed. See console for info.\n%s\n%s\n" % (stdout, stderr))
    173   finally:
    174     # Must manually cleanup files.

ConverterError: TOCO failed. See console for info.
2019-06-28 17:04:12.512364: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: RFFT
2019-06-28 17:04:12.512817: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1426] OpKernel ('op: "NoOp" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: NoOp
2019-06-28 17:04:12.513084: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1426] OpKernel ('op: "NoOp" device_type: "GPU"') for unknown op: NoOp
2019-06-28 17:04:12.513269: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1426] OpKernel ('op: "_HostRecv" device_type: "GPU" host_memory_arg: "tensor"') for unknown op: _HostRecv
2019-06-28 17:04:12.513564: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1426] OpKernel ('op: "_Send" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: _Send
2019-06-28 17:04:12.513819: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1426] OpKernel ('op: "_HostRecv" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: _HostRecv
2019-06-28 17:04:12.514068: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1426] OpKernel ('op: "_Send" device_type: "GPU"') for unknown op: _Send
2019-06-28 17:04:12.514254: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1426] OpKernel ('op: "_Recv" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: _Recv
2019-06-28 17:04:12.514431: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1426] OpKernel ('op: "_HostSend" device_type: "GPU" host_memory_arg: "tensor"') for unknown op: _HostSend
2019-06-28 17:04:12.514637: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1426] OpKernel ('op: "_Recv" device_type: "GPU"') for unknown op: _Recv
2019-06-28 17:04:12.514803: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1426] OpKernel ('op: "_HostSend" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: _HostSend
2019-06-28 17:04:12.515019: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1426] OpKernel ('op: "WrapDatasetVariant" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: WrapDatasetVariant
2019-06-28 17:04:12.515234: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1426] OpKernel ('op: "WrapDatasetVariant" device_type: "GPU" host_memory_arg: "input_handle" host_memory_arg: "output_handle"') for unknown op: WrapDatasetVariant
2019-06-28 17:04:12.515498: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1426] OpKernel ('op: "UnwrapDatasetVariant" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: UnwrapDatasetVariant
2019-06-28 17:04:12.515718: E tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1426] OpKernel ('op: "UnwrapDatasetVariant" device_type: "GPU" host_memory_arg: "input_handle" host_memory_arg: "output_handle"') for unknown op: UnwrapDatasetVariant
2019-06-28 17:04:12.516175: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1385] Unable to determine output type for op: RFFT
2019-06-28 17:04:12.516336: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: ComplexAbs
2019-06-28 17:04:12.516712: I tensorflow/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39] Before Removing unused ops: 7 operators, 17 arrays (0 quantized)
2019-06-28 17:04:12.517018: I tensorflow/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39] Before general graph transformations: 7 operators, 17 arrays (0 quantized)
2019-06-28 17:04:12.517417: I tensorflow/lite/toco/graph_transformations/graph_transformations.cc:39] After general graph transformations pass 1: 7 operators, 16 arrays (0 quantized)
2019-06-28 17:04:12.517682: F tensorflow/lite/toco/graph_transformations/propagate_fixed_sizes.cc:118] Check failed: dim_x == dim_y (64 vs. 256)Dimensions must match
Fatal Python error: Aborted

Current thread 0x000033dc (most recent call first):
  File "f:\anaconda3\envs\tf_py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\toco\python\toco_from_protos.py", line 33 in execute
  File "f:\anaconda3\envs\tf_py36\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 251 in _run_main
  File "f:\anaconda3\envs\tf_py36\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 300 in run
  File "f:\anaconda3\envs\tf_py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 40 in run
  File "f:\anaconda3\envs\tf_py36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\toco\python\toco_from_protos.py", line 59 in main
  File "F:\Anaconda3\envs\tf_py36\Scripts\toco_from_protos.exe\__main__.py", line 9 in <module>
  File "f:\anaconda3\envs\tf_py36\lib\runpy.py", line 85 in _run_code
  File "f:\anaconda3\envs\tf_py36\lib\runpy.py", line 193 in _run_module_as_main
```

I want to make customize Spectrogram library by [`tf.signal.stft`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/signal/stft) function, and save to `.tflite` file for using in Android device.
I can't find anymore tutorial about TFLite converter, only the official document. Please help me to fix this error, thanks a lots !!

Comment: The error message says:
ConverterError: TOCO failed. See console for info.
```2019-06-28 17:04:12.512364: I tensorflow/lite/toco/import_tensorflow.cc:1336] Converting unsupported operation: RFFT```
That's means I can't convert the session with tf.signal.stft  function? 

Comment: The new discussion on [Tensorflow Lite Forum](https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/tflite/R0srfl9wvGk)

Comment: There is documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/faq#why_are_some_operations_not_implemented_in_tensorflow_lite) on converting models with unsupported ops.

Comment: Tensorflow seems to have an open issue related to this: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27303
It sounds like they are planning to fix RFFT. Meanwhile if you found a workaround please share...